# Generate Primary Key for records with ZERO ("0")

Tags: sql-server

In my table, a Primary Key is generated as the DEFAULT option for column with NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE. After inserting a record with a NULL value in the PK column, the Key is autogenerated. I need same operation when **0** is inserted in the PK column. I can't use an after trigger (need to generate PK before insert) and using instead of trigger also does not help because I need to create temporary table each time which causes a decrease in performance.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. The idea of a `SEQUENCE`/`IDENTITY` is that you don't pass the value so that the `DEFAULT` value is used. Why are you *trying* to pass `0` for the value at all..?

Comment: An `AFTER` trigger is about the only realistic solution if you can't modify clients to pass correct data or use stored procedures instead. It's not clear why you'd "need to create a temporary table each time"; a single `INSERT` where you select the data from `inserted` should be all you need. Note that you can also define these on views, for additional flexibility.

Comment: As @JeroenMostert mentioned, i cannot modify clients to pass correct data, so i would like to treat 0 as null. The problem is if I want to add 10 records at once, where some pk are defined, some are empty, and some are equal to 0. What i mean saying "need to create a temporary table each time", is that, in instead of trigger i need to modify table before insert, so i need to create one, cuz inserted table cannot be modified, and i cannot imagine how to replace those values using only select.

Comment: Then you need two inserts in the trigger, one inserting the rows for the 0 values, one inserting all the other rows (using `WHERE`). One will omit the PK column, one will not. A single statement using `CASE` is also a possibility, but not if the column has to be omitted to get the default value.

Comment: This sounds extremely brittle to me. You receive a primary key from an external source sometimes and you keep that key. How do you handle collisions? Not just from the external data but also from your sequence.

Comment: I know it's a bit awkward solution, but i got such requirements. If collisions exists mssql does not allow to insert records. Value of sequence is updated after every insert, and is set as higest value of PK +1.